# c++ linked list, removing element disconnects the rest of the list

Tags: c++, class, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I was trying to implement this simple linked list project for my homework. When I tried to implement the `removeByKey` function, I ran into the problem that it disconnects the rest of the list entirely when it finds the key to be removed.

Here's the class:

```
class LancElem
{
private:
    int key;
    LancElem* next;
public:
    LancElem(){next = nullptr;}
    LancElem(int keyy, LancElem* nextt){key = keyy;next = nextt;}
    LancElem* getNext(){return next;}
    int getKey(){return key;}
    void setNext(LancElem* nextt){next = nextt; }
    void setKey(int keyy){key = keyy;}
};
```

The remove fucntion:

```
void removeByKey(LancElem& head, int key){
    LancElem* n = head.getNext();
    while(n->getNext()!=nullptr){
        if(n->getNext()->getKey()==key){
            n->setNext(n->getNext()->getNext());
            delete n->getNext();
            break;
        }
        n=n->getNext();
    }
}
```

When I try to remove the biggest element:

The original linked list: `4 1 9 8 2 7 3 6 3`

Expected output: `4 1 8 2 7 3 6 3`

The real output: `4 1 0`

The problem is probably where I connect the current element to the next->next element but I can't figure out why my implementation isn't good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask yourself:

What is `n->next` after the line `n->setNext(n->getNext()->getNext());` ? What does the line `delete n->getNext();` delete?

You don't want to `delete` the just updated `next` but you want to delete the to be removed element:

```
        auto to_be_deleted = n->getNext(); 
        n->setNext(to_be_deleted->getNext());
        delete to_be_deleted;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your list has a dummy head node that does not have a value.

The function `removeByKey` can invoke undefined behavior when `head.getNext()`   returns a null pointer due to using the expression `n->getNext()`

```
LancElem* n = head.getNext();
while(n->getNext()!=nullptr){
```

Also within the if statement

```
    if(n->getNext()->getKey()==key){
        n->setNext(n->getNext()->getNext());
        delete n->getNext();
        break;
    }
```

you are trying to delete a node after the node to be deleted due to preceding assignment of the data member `next` by using the function `setNext`.

```
        n->setNext(n->getNext()->getNext());
        delete n->getNext();
```

Pay attention to that your function is unable to delete the node after the dummy head node due to using by you two times the call of `getNext()`

```
LancElem* n = head.getNext();  // the first call of getNext
while(n->getNext()!=nullptr){
    if(n->getNext()->getKey()==key){   // the second call of getNext.
    //...
```

The function can be defined like

```
void removeByKey( LancElem &head, int key )
{
    if ( head.getNext() != nullptr )
    {
        if ( head.getNext()->getKey() == key )
        {
            LancElem *current = head.getNext();
            head.setNext( head.getNext()->getNext() );
            delete current;
        }
        else
        {
            LancElem *n = head.getNext();

            while( n->getNext() != nullptr && n->getNext()->getKey() != key )
            {
                n = n->getNext();
            }

            if ( n->getNext() != nullptr )
            {
                LancElem *current = n->getNext();
                n->setNext( n->getNext()->getNext() );
                delete current;
            }                
        }
    }
}
```

Now try to use this function to delete the first node with the value 4 of your list and the function you currently have and compare their results.